# MIL STD 1553 Transceiver Current Drawn and Power Consumption

Tags: mil-std-1553

I will communicate with the MCU with the HI-2130GPIF mil std1553 transreciver spi protocol. I will use an ldo to feed the transreciever in my design, but I have some doubts. Assuming that it is powered by a 3.3V power supply "for a bus" in the datasheet, it is mentioned that 3.3V × 720mA typical = 2.4W power consumption. The mil std 1553 protocol I was wondering has a redundant bus structure. Are the two buses not running at the same time? Or does the other bus continue to consume power when one bus dies?
I will assume that it consumes 4.8watts of power in that case.

[image]

[image]

[Transreciever Datasheet](https://smallpdf.com/result#r=f750642a32eebbf16ed49d4d1b7ee22a&t=share-document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MIL-STD-1553, only one bus transmits at a time. The controller decides which bus is used. If you are designing the controller, then you are resposible for this behavior.

The controller also usually has settings for the retry sequence, same bus or alternate bus for the first retry, and the same bus or alternate bus for the second retry.

Both receivers are normally active, but the controller can disable one of them if it believes that it is receiving garbage.